# Function overriding in Java vs C++

Tags: java, c++, polymorphism, overriding

Two similar definitions in Java and C++, but totally different behaviour.

Java version:

```
class base{
    public void func1(){
        func2();
    }
    public void func2(){
        System.out.println(" I am in base:func2() \n");
    }

}

class derived extends base{
    public void func1(){
        super.func1();
    }
    public void func2(){
        System.out.println(" I am in derived:func2() \n");
    }
};
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        derived d = new derived();
        d.func1();
    }
}
```

output:

```
I am in derived:func2()
```

C++ version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class base
{
    public:
        void func1(){
            func2();
        }
        void func2(){
            printf(" I am in base:func2() \n");
        }
};

class derived : public base
{
    public:
        void func1(){
            base::func1();
        }
        void func2(){
            printf(" I am in derived:func2() \n");
        }
};

int main()
{
    derived *d = new derived();
    d->func1();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
I am in base:func2()
```

---

I don't know why they have different behaviour.

Even I know Java has auto polymorphism behaviour.

The Java output is hard to understand personally.

<del>In my view, according to `static scope`, the base class function `func1()` should only be able to  call the base class function `func2()`, as it knows nothing about the derived class at all. Otherwise the calling behaviour belongs to `dynamic scope`.
Maybe in C++, `func2()` in base class is bind `static`, but in Java it is bind `dynamic`?</del>

Member field is statically scoped.

---

The type inferring part is confusing.
I thought `this` is converted to `base` type in the `base::func1()`. In C++, the `base::func2()` is not polymorphism, so the `base::func1()` is called.
While in Java, `base::func2()` is polymorphism, so `devried::func2()` is called.

How the `func2()` class binding being inferred? Or
Which `fun2()` should be called and how it is determined.

What happened behind `base::func1()`? Is there any cast here for `this` (from `derive` to `base`)?
If no, how `this` is able to reach to the function in `base` class?

```
        void func1(){
            func2();
        }
```

---

[Useful discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/381808/java/java/Java-differences-function-overriding) on coderanch.

Comment: I am sorry, but it is the last part of my comment.  I really want to know how the type inference is implemented when calling `func2()` from `base::func1()`.

Comment: Do you mean *How the `func2()` class binding being inferred?*

Comment: Exactly. Which `fun2()` should be called and how it is determined.

Comment: Expanded my answer. Please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Your expansion is great. But it would be more helpful if things behind `base::func1()` is explained.

Comment: Made yet an attempt to explain. You're not super clear about what you find confusing. Asking me to explain "things behind `base::func1()`" sort of forces me to guess.

Comment: No, the class itself is really not enough to infer `func2()` belong to `base` or `derive`.  If `func2()` is *virtual*, then how to infer it belongs to which class?

Comment: If it is virtual, it is the *runtime type* that determines which class it "belongs" to, i.e. the actual type of the object during execution.

Comment: Previously, I thought all the function inferring is done though the casting `this` pointer, it seems `this` is only a pointer which stands for receiver object, it is used to find out the relative position of member field and function only.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Java all methods that can be overridden are automatically [virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function). There is no opt-in mechanism (`virtual` keyword) for it as it is in C++ (and there's no way to opt-out either).

Java behaves as if you had declared `base::func2` as

```
virtual void func2(){
    printf(" I am in base:func2() \n");
}
```

In which case your program would have printed `"I am in derived:func2()"`.

> How the `func2()` class binding being inferred?
>   Which `fun2()` should be called and how it is determined.

For non-virtual methods (C++ methods without `virtual` modifier) it is the *static type* that determines which method to call. The static type of the variable is determined by the variable declaration and does not depend on how the code is executed.

For virtual methods (C++ methods with the `virtual` modifier and *all* Java methods) it is the *runtime type* that determines which method to call. The runtime type is the type of the actual object in runtime.

**Example:** If you have

```
Fruit f = new Banana();
```

the static type of `f` is `Fruit` and the runtime type of `f` is `Banana`.

If you do `f.someNonVirtualMethod()` the static type will be used and `Fruit::someNonVirtualMethod` will be called. If you do `f.someVirtualMethod()` the runtime type will be used and `Banana::someVirtualMethod` will be called.

The underlying implementation for how the compiler achieves this is basically implementation dependent, but typically a vtable is used. For details refer to

- [How Vtable of Virtual functions work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065088/how-vtable-of-virtual-functions-work)
- [How does virtual method invocation work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804079/how-does-virtual-method-invocation-work-in-c)
- [Mechanism of Vptr and Vtable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224126/mechanism-of-vptr-and-vtable-in-c)

---

> If no, how `this` is able to reach to the function in `base` class?
>
> ```
> void func1(){
>     func2();
> }
> ```

If you're wondering why `func2()` here calls `base`'s `func2` it is because

A) You're in the scope of `base` which means that the static type of `this` is `base`, and

B) `func2` in `base` is *not* virtual, so it is the static type that decides which implementation to call.

Comment: (And conversely, making a method `final` does let you "opt out"...)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes and no. It is the decision of the base class to not let the sub classes override a method when it is final. You even cannot declare a method with the same signature. As far as I understand, that is somewhat different to C++.

Comment: If a method can't be overridden it's meaningless to discuss whether it's virtual or not. I'd say private, final and static methods are neither virtual nor non-virtual because no one knows which method would be called if someone managed to override it.

Comment: But how to understand the `base::func1()` ? Does it mean to change the `this` from `derived` type to `base` type?

Comment: What happened when `base::func1()` is called? As it has something to do with the `func2()` in the base function. How the `func2()` class binding being inferred?

Comment: This is typically implemented by having a method lookup table (a v-table). The base class overrides the entry in the table corresponding to `func2` so that `func2` is automatically called when invoking it on a `derived` object. Have a look at the Wikipedia article on [Virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Comment: Well, if you have a `private` method, there *can* be a method with identical signature in the subclass which still doesn’t override the former. With package-private access, the picture might get really complicated…

Comment: Right. But as you say, it *doesn't* override it, so while it's kind of related, it still doesn't prove that private methods are non-virtual.

Comment: Does it mean the behaviour of `base::func1()` is determined by the `class` it is in, but not inferred from the type of `this`? But `base` class really knows nothing of its `derive`!

Comment: @aioobe: how do you define “non-virtual” then, if the absence of a virtual method call (actual runtime class based arbitration) does not suffice?

Comment: Wow, you got me :-) I'm now convinced it makes sense to say that private methods in Java are non-virtual. Thanks for hammering this into my head.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ **you can only override a base class function if it is declared `virtual`**. Since in your c++ example you haven't declared 'func2()' as [virtual](https://pencilprogrammer.com/cpp-tutorials/virtual-function/) so it has not been overridden by derived class 'func2()`.

Whereas in Java you don't need to declare a function in the base class as virtual in order to override them.

Consider this Java example.

```
class Base{
  public void func2(){
    System.out.println("Base class func2()");
  }
}

class Derived extends Base{
  public void func2(){
    System.out.println("Derived class func2()");
  }
}

class Main extends Base{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Derived derived = new Derived();
    derived.func2();

    Base base = new Derived();
    base.func2();
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Derived class func2()
Derived class func2()
```

If you want to declare a base class function as non-virtual in java, then declare that function as `final`. This will prevent the override of base class function in the derived class.

Example:

```
class Base{
  public final void func2(){
    System.out.println("Base class func2()");
  }
}
```

*Some external links belong to my site.*

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [the help center on self-promotion](/help/promotion). Disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. When it's your own *personal* content, it can just be something like "on my site…", "on my blog…", etc.